# Gremlin parameterised query for addV() with unbounded number of property

Tags: gremlin

How do I write a parameterised gremlin query to add a vertex with many number of properties. I want to parameterise the property in such a way that.. I should be able to pass the properties in a Map and the query to read and insert all those into the vertex. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible with a script where you construct the traversal on the remote side and, then, only possible for graph systems that support scripts in that way (e.g. wouldn't work on CosmosDB). You would just send your script as the following where `m` is your `Map`:

```
t = g.addV()
m.each{k,v -> t= t.property(k,v)]
t
```

Comment: ok. I think it is better to prepare the entire query string like - g.addV().property('<key>',<'value'>).... and sent it. though the script you mentioned is small, it has a short coming of few Gremlin implementations not supporting it